# Single word that can be used for both tip/gratuity and donation

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a web api and a single field is used for both tips and donations. Is there a single word that works for this? I've thought of things like "additional" (not descriptive enough) and "extra amount" (not terse as I'd like). Right now I have the api parameter as "extra_amount", but if there's a single word for this that is more descriptive and a single word I'd love to use it instead.

Comment: Offering, contribution, gifting.

Comment: How are you distinguishing tips from donations?

Comment: @curiousdannii There is not really a need to distinguish in this situation. These are not created by the people doing the tipping/donations, so any differentiation will be known and irrelevant to the user.

Comment: If you don't need to distinguish them, then why not just pick one of those words?

Comment: In my mind- tips and donations are not the same at all.  If I give a donation I am attempting to help a cause and could reasonably expect a receipt.  If I am tipping I am adding a gratuity for services rendered.

Comment: @Jim right, typically yes. However, functionally they represent the same thing: an optional chosen amount of money that is added on to a specific cost (which could be $0 in the case of a donation). This is for the same of designing a data interface so it needs to be intuitive to whoever is working with the interface, while not to the general public.

Comment: @curiousdannii because it should be clear to any developers working with the api what it's function is. I originally called it tip, but feedback stated that it was unclear it could be used for donations as well (unsurprisingly)

Comment: @Jim That may depend on your culture - in the US tips are more obligatory. But on the internet existing tip services seem very much identical to donation services with almost no sense of obligation.

Comment: @S.Buda- My point was that even though they may behave the same from a math perspective, they might need to be treated or tagged separately for audit/tax/accounting purposes- I don't know your application so perhaps you're ok, just wanted you to at least think about it.

Comment: If the field is for tips and donations, then why not call it *Tips_and_Donations*, instead of looking for some elusive word that future maintainers will need to decipher as "tips & donations"? As you said, "it should be clear to any developers working with the api what it's  [sic] function is."

Answer (score 1):

You could lump both types together as ***discretionary*** or ***voluntary*** payments...

> [**discretionary**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/discretionary) *- left to or regulated by one's own discretion or judgment.*
>
> [**voluntary**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/voluntary) *- done or undertaken of one's own free will*

I probably wouldn't go for ***optional***, but it's a possibility.